# Classify all the finite groups with $4$ conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Classify all the finite groups up to an isomorphism with exactly four conjugacy classes. By the Landau Theorem we obtain that the groups have order  $<43$. Can you help me with some ideas or some articles about that problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper

Antonio Vera López, Juan Vera López, *Classification of finite groups according to the number of conjugacy classes*, Israel Journal of Mathematics, December 1985, Volume 51, Issue 4, pp 305-338,

available [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02764723), lists all finite groups with at most $11$ conjugacy classes.  In particular, it seems the only finite groups with exactly $4$ conjugacy classes are $C_4$, $C_2\times C_2$, $D_{10}$ and $A_4$.